# Xbee S2C device attached to desktop with Ubuntu OS connected to USB port is not displayed under device manager section

Tags: networking, usb

I am not able to find the Xbee S2c device that I have connected to USB port of a desktop with Ubuntu in the device manager section. That particular USB port is fine and the Xbee S2C device is on (red light).

Comment: Much more detail is needed. You have not even said what version of Ubuntu you are using. What is this device? What does it do? Based on what is written here there is nothing to help with.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting